# SublimeREPL prompt garbled

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, sublimetext, sublimerepl

I'm using SublimeREPL in MacOS Big Sur, and I'm trying to launch the REPL for Python with `virtualenv`, but what I see at the prompt is something like this:

```
Warning: Output is not a terminal (fd=1).
Warning: Input is not a terminal (fd=0).
Jupyter console 6.4.0

Python 3.8.9 (default, Apr  9 2021, 19:58:33) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.26.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

[?2004h[?1l[?25l[?7l;5;28mIn [;5;46;1m1;5;28m]: [?7h[?12l[?25h
```

Main.sublime-menu in SublimeREPL > config > Python only contains this for `Python - virtualenv`:

```
    {"command": "python_virtualenv_repl",
     "id": "python_virtualenv_repl",
     "caption": "Python - virtualenv"
    },
```

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

In your virtualenv root there should be a (hidden) folder called `.ipython/`. Open `.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` and add the line

```py
c.InteractiveShell.colors = "NoColor"
```

to it. That *should* take care of the problem.

NOTE: If you can't find `.ipython/` in your virtualenv root folder, check your home folder (`C:\Users\username`, `/Users/username`, or `/home/username` for Windows, macOS, and Linux, respectively), as it may be there.

Comment: Thanks for replying! It didn't work though... Tested many different ways of putting `InteractiveShell` under `virtualenv` and home folder `.ipython`, but no luck!